# Log Files in HBase

Tags: logging, hadoop, hbase

Where will be the HLog files are stored in HBase. Currently i am using HBase on top of my local file system instead of HDFS, I wanted to observe how HBase is logging the details for each operation like put. How can i observe that?
I wanted to check how it is handling the user given timestamp

Answer (score 2):

**Logs**

Most of the information in the log files are about the connection and transactions between the different nodes. By default they can be found in the `HBASE_HOME` directory. Another directory can be specified in `hbase-env.sh`.

```
HMaster: $HBASE_HOME/logs/hbase-<user>-master-<hostname>.log
RegionServer: $HBASE_HOME/logs/hbase-<user>-regionserver-<hostname>.log
```

**Metrics**

You won't find single HBase transaction information in these log files. For this you could use metrics BUT these will by default only show the operations that vary from the vast majority of successful queries.

Have a look here: 
http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops.monitoring.html

**Custom**

Why don't you write a custom logger in your client side application? A lot of information is available through the Java API and this way you have great control over what you want to have in your 'log' file.

Comment: Thanx @Pieterjan Instead of HDFS i am using my own local file system. so only one system i am using which handles regionserver,Hmaster, zookeeper. First file(which you specified) does not contain any information about the transaction(single row) details, it contains information about load balancing. where will be the second file located in the case of single system.

Comment: I am checking how HBase is able to recover in the case of memstore getting crashed....can you please check this question [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427857/recovery-in-hbase)