# How Recovery works in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I wanted to observe practically How Recovery Works in HBase, i had used the following snippet of code

```
    Put p=new Put(Bytes.toBytes("name10"));
    p.setWriteAheadLog(true);
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes("Some Value 10"));
    table.setAutoFlush(true);
    table.put(p);
```

After executing the above code i restarted my VM **(without stopping HBase)** and started the HBase, when i scanned through this table the Rowkey name10 was not showing up. Where as, when i properly **stopped** the HBase instance and **restarted the VM**, it is showing perfectly(Since from MemStore the HBase pushed the  data into HBase tables).
      Although, my WAL was enabled why it's not able to recover. Is there any wrong in my understanding?
   Where will be the WAL files are stored?I am using HBase on top of my local file system instead of HDFS....Where can i check the WAL files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAL files gets stored in .logs folder(hidden). In Stand alone mode it will takes time to write into WAL, where as in Pseudo Distributed mode it will works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

After putting the data in table .
Run " flush tablename" from hbase shell. 
then check

Comment: Thanx for the reply...."flush tablename" is working fine...since, "flush tablename" is similar to closing HBase properly...I wanted to check the recovery from WAL if we won't flush or stop the HBase properly...Do you have an idea where the Log files will gets stored in local file system and how to read them?

Comment: I hope it is stored in hbase.rootdir/.logs directory . hbase.rootdir is the directory that you configured in hbase-site.xml

Comment: what type of files are they ?

Comment: For each table there is a corresponding file containing -> column families -> which internally contains two more files ...for these files there is no extension...i tried to open it in Hex Editor it's not dispaying any information..in properties it is showing 1kb size

Comment: I have HBase running on HDFS. I browsed the file system thorugh hadoop UI and I can read the contents of logfiles there

Comment: I am giving my own time stamp while i am putting values into HBase table, will the WAL files includes the time stamp parameter or internal time stamp...Thanx for the reply