# WAL file in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In **Standalone mode(local file system)** will HBase uses the Concept of Write Ahead Logging for recovery...If so where will be this WAL file?.....I wanted to check the recovery of HBase practically, so i am doing this experiment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In every mode either it's Standalone or Distributed it uses WAL file, but it takes time to update in WAL file in Stand alone mode

Answer (score 1):

the WAL is always used, the only way to not write to the wal is by setting put.setWriteToWAL(false)

The files are stored in /hbase/.logs//
the /hbase folder is by default in /tmp on local filesystem but you can check your hbase.rootdir in hbase-site.xml

I'm not sure what do you mean by "I wanted to check the recovery of HBase practically"
the logs are just used in case of failure, to replay the (memstore) data that was not written to disk.

This two blog posts explains the write-path and the log replay
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/07/hbase-log-splitting/

Comment: Thanx...can you please check this [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470122/how-recovery-works-in-hbase)

Comment: You can read the log files using the HLogPrettyPrinter util
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogPrettyPrinter <filename>
there are options for more output

Comment: thanx for the reply...can you send me any reference links for that regarding how to run that....